# Show all records when a filter option is not selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a web site using php and MySQL.  On one of my pages I have a select query with a few parameters passed by a form.
On my form there is a `<select>` box:

```
<select name="courseCode">
    <option value="" selected>Show All</option>
    <option value="1">Emergency First Aid</option>
    <option value="2">Advanced Burns Training</option>
    <option value="3">Fire Safety</option>
    <option value="4">Environmental Awareness</option>
</select>
```

There are also options to set a from date and to date.

The problem I'm facing is in my php when the Show All option is used, it doesn't fetch all the records and I not sure of the best way to write it

```
<?php
    $min = "2016-01-01"; // Default search criteria for 
    $max = "2016-12-31"; // date ranges to search
    $code;

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $min = $_GET['min'];
        $max = $_GET['max'];
        $code = $_GET['courseCode'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT tblcourses.Course_Name, tblclasses.Class_OnDate, tblclasses.Class_TimeStart, tblclasses.Class_TimeFinish, Class_MaxAllowed
            FROM tblcourses INNER JOIN tblclasses ON tblcourses.Course_Code = tblclasses.Course_Code
            WHERE (tblclasses.Class_OnDate Between '$min' and '$max') AND (tblclasses.Course_Code = '$code')
            ORDER BY tblclasses.Class_OnDate ASC;";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
<?php

$min = "2016-01-01"; // Default search criteria for 
$max = "2016-12-31"; // date ranges to search
$code;
$filterWithCode = '';

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $min = $_GET['min'];
  $max = $_GET['max'];
  $code = $_GET['courseCode'];
  if($code){
    $filterWithCode = " AND (tblclasses.Course_Code = '$code') ";
  }
}


$sql = "SELECT tblcourses.Course_Name, tblclasses.Class_OnDate, tblclasses.Class_TimeStart, tblclasses.Class_TimeFinish, Class_MaxAllowed
            FROM tblcourses INNER JOIN tblclasses ON tblcourses.Course_Code = tblclasses.Course_Code
            WHERE (tblclasses.Class_OnDate Between '$min' and '$max') $filterWithCode
            ORDER BY tblclasses.Class_OnDate ASC;";
```

Comment: I had coded it similar to what you suggested this at one point, but felt that this issue might must be a common thing among developers and so thought I was missing out on a function or trick to make things easier

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be something like

```
if ($code == '')
    $sql = "SELECT without WHERE";
else
    $sql = "SELECT with WHERE";
```

Incidentally, you really should be doing this as a prepared statement, which means you need to use either `mysqli` or `PDO` (which you should be doing anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php
    $min = "2016-01-01"; // Default search criteria for 
    $max = "2016-12-31"; // date ranges to search
    $code;

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $min = $_GET['min'];
        $max = $_GET['max'];
        $code = $_GET['courseCode'];
    }

    if($code){  
      $sql = "SELECT tblcourses.Course_Name, tblclasses.Class_OnDate, tblclasses.Class_TimeStart, tblclasses.Class_TimeFinish, Class_MaxAllowed
            FROM tblcourses INNER JOIN tblclasses ON tblcourses.Course_Code = tblclasses.Course_Code
            WHERE (tblclasses.Class_OnDate Between '$min' and '$max') AND (tblclasses.Course_Code = '$code')
            ORDER BY tblclasses.Class_OnDate ASC;";
    } else{
       $sql = "SELECT tblcourses.Course_Name, tblclasses.Class_OnDate, tblclasses.Class_TimeStart, tblclasses.Class_TimeFinish, Class_MaxAllowed
            FROM tblcourses INNER JOIN tblclasses ON tblcourses.Course_Code = tblclasses.Course_Code
            ORDER BY tblclasses.Class_OnDate ASC;";
    }
```

hope it helps :)